# Wrong parsing with ANTLR4's C.g4

Tags: antlr4

Edit: I've added this as an issue on ANTLR's github: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/issues/95.

I'm parsing the following code using ANTLR version 4.3 and C.g4 taken from https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/c/C.g4:

```
void bad()
    {
    foo(a);
    }
```

The grammar interprets the `foo(a)` as `declaration`, but it should be a `postfixExpression`. I've pasted the wrong parse tree here.

It can be interpreted correctly by changing the order of `declaration` and `statement` in the `blockItem` rule. Does doing that break something else?

[image: Wrong parse tree]

Comment: Seems like bug for me, too. You should raise an issue at github. I wonder why there is no ambiguity between the two alternatives...

Comment: Ok. However, I added a different issue a few days ago but no one has solved it. I assume they are busy elsewhere, so I was looking for a fix here.

Comment: There is no ambiguity since it's automatically resolved in favour of the first alternative, i.e. a declaration as Ter mentioned! Maybe if one renamed "declaration" to "maybeDeclarationOrSomethingElse" it would be clearer ;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

foo(a); is a valid declaration, foo a;, as well as expression.  The C11 spec shows:

`blockItem
    :   declaration
    |   statement
    ;`

Which ANTLR interprets as resolving any ambiguities to the declaration. W/o symbol table information, this cannot be resolved. :(